# Check chekbox when value of another element is changed

Tags: php, jquery

I want to check checkbox when value of "select" is changed. No idea what is wrong with this code, maybe you will be able to see the mistake:

```
var selected; var div_id;

$(".live_editor_test").focus(function() { 
    selected = $(this).val();
    div_id = $(this).closest("div").attr('id');
});

$(".live_editor_test").blur(function() {
    if (selected != $(this).val()) { 
        $('#live-assigning_check_' + div_id).attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

- `live_editor_test` is the class of the `select`.
- `div` is the row element and parent of `live_editor_test`.
- `live-assigning_check` is the checkbox id.
- `div_id` increments as there is one row for each mySql query.

Thanks in advance.

.php :

```
echo "<span class='content-row live-row-8' style=\"$colorcov\">";
echo "<select class=\"live_editor_test\" name=\"live_editor[$i]\" style=\"width:65px;font-size:10px;\">";
echo "<option value=\"\" selected></option>";

foreach ($storage_access->userAuth($row1, $where) as $row45)
{
if ($row45->match_id > '0') { $selected = "selected"; } else { $selected = ""; }
echo "<option value=\"$row45->user_id\" $selected>$row45->user_name</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</span>";
echo "<span style=\"width:20px;display:table-cell;\"><input class='checkbox-row' id='live-assigning_check_$i' type='checkbox' name='checked[$i]' ></span>";
```

Comment: Can you also post the HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. Also use change event for select box.

Note: assuming that `'#live-assigning_check_' + div_id` evaluates to valid checkbox id.

```
$(".live_editor_test").change(function() {
    if (selected != $(this).val()) { 
        $('#live-assigning_check_' + div_id).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried that, but still nothing.

Comment: Have you checked `live-assigning_check_' + div_id` evaluates to valid checkbox id? Can you pass a jsfiddle link with your problem statement?

Comment: Actually is php file is too big and with mysql queries. But how can I check if  `live-assigning_check_' + div_id` is valid?

Comment: You can do inspect element by right clicking on the checkbox and see if checkbox and its parent div has the id in sync. Also can debug the javascript using [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: Yes they are in sync. Can be a problem that I am using the script in php file? I used alert() inside the same `<script>` and it worked.

Comment: check for console errors on browser. If nothing then remove `if (selected != $(this).val())` condition and check if checkbox get checked. If not then put alert('#live-assigning_check_' + div_id) and check what it shows and does it match with your checkbox id. Also put your jquery inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: really lol. The problem was only `$(document).ready(function(){`});` I added and it started to work. Thanks a lot! you saved my day.

Comment: happy to help you :)